# Error while running Puppet Agent using class in node default

Tags: puppet

I am getting error while executing puppet *script*

on Puppet master `site.pp` file I wrote following code

```rb
node default {
  class t {
    package {'apache2':
      ensure => installed,
    }
  }
}
```

---

On Slave machine when i execute it using `puppet agent --test`, it throws the error:

```
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Retrieving locales
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Could not parse for environment production: Classes, definitions, and nodes may only appear at toplevel or inside other classes (file: /etc/puppet/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp, line: 3, column: 1) on node slave.ec2.internal
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Can you please help me in this regard

Answer (score 3):

Hi this is because you are not supposed to define classes inside `site.pp`

Have a module `foo` (as I prefer `foo` for examples instead of `t`) defined like this:

```rb
#modules/foo/manifests/init.pp
class foo {
  package {'apache2':
      ensure => installed,
  }
}
```

and you have a node entry in your site.pp like this

```rb
# site.pp
node default {
  include 'foo'
}
```

Comment: ... or for such a simple case, one could just forget about any classes and declare the `Package` directly in the node block.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, you are right. I wanted to remain as close as possible to his example, so that I do not *suggest** in any ways that *classes should be avoided*. For anyone reading this answer, `class`-es can be avoided for simplicity.